# Right of someone unknown

Tags: human-rights, cheating

I am a 17 year old currently studying intermediate. The intermediate education is provided by colleges in my country. In my secondary exams (on the basis of which students get admission in college for inter) I remember I asked a question of a friend during the exam to confirm a doubt. Now I realize that by doing that I may have disfavoured someone else who did not cheat. Now, I am in the final year of inter. Should I discontinue studies because studying in this college may have been someone else's right?

Answer (score 0):

If you have cheated someone and you are regret for that and you think that you have done wrong then you should apologize to him,but if this is not in your control to apologize to him then you don't need to apologize to him.But you have to repent sincerely to Allah and you have to be firm that you will never do this again.

Allah says in Quran:
[ Tell them( O Prophet)," My servants who have committed excesses against themselves( committed sins) ,do not lose hope in Allah's mercy .Surely Allah forgives all sins .He is the most forgiving most merciful.]. (39:53)

No matter what sins a person has committed ,if he then repents sincerely to Allah and begins to obey him ,Allah will turn to him in mercy ,expiate his bad deeds ,raise him in status and turn his bad deeds into good deeds,and his state   after repenting will be better than it was before he committed the sin,because repentance erases the sins that came before it and the one who repents from sin is like one who did not commit sin at all.

Allah says in Quran:
[ Except for those who repent , believe and do righteous work.For them Allah will replace their evil deeds with good.Allah is the most forgiving most merciful.]
(25:70)

So you do not need to discontinue your studies,trust in Allah that He will forgive you.

Please tell me if this answer is helpful for you or not. Assalamualaikum

Comment: Really helpfull thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply